# Lowest and highest number in an array

Tags: java

here is my code

```
 private static void stats(String[] args) {
if (args.length == 1) {
  System.out.print("Error: Argument count mismatch");
  return;
}
int[] array = {0};
double average = 0.0;
int total = 0;
int count = 0;
int max = array[0];
int min = max;
for (int i = 1;i < args.length;i++) {
  if (isInteger(args[i]) == false) {
    System.out.print("Error: Argument type mismatch");
    return;
  }
  else {
    count++;
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    total += a;
    average = total / count;
    max = a;
    for (int d = 1; d < array.length; d++) {
      if (array[d] > max) {
        max = array[d];
      }
      if (array[d] < min) { // change to > for largest
        min = array[d];
      }
    }
  }
}
System.out.println("Total " + total);
System.out.println("Max " + max);
System.out.println("Min " + min);
System.out.printf("Average " + "%.2f\n" , average);
```

}

for some reason it won't print out the max and min values, I tried a couple of things and my idea is that I might need to declare max and min again, but to what?

Comment: Well currently the array only ever has the value `0` in it... did you intend to change that somewhere? And why are you just assigning `max = a;` on every iteration?

Comment: There are a lot of questionable things going on here. Why are you calculating averages and sums if you just want the highest and lowest number? You should be able to do this with a single loop.

Comment: Delete max = a; before the for loop it makes no sense to be there

Comment: i am trying to get the average and total as well, but currently I have some problems finding the highest and lowest number,

Comment: I deleted it, it was something I added by mistake

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I intend to add the parsed int arguments in the array.

Comment: Please, for readability, use proper indentation and whitespace in your code examples.

Comment: Right, so I would suggest that the *first* thing you should do is separate the problem into two parts: 1) Create an array (or a `List<Integer>`) from the user input; 2) work out the min/max/total/average. Note that you can test part 2 without actually implementing part 1, just by hard-coding the values...

Comment: better not to implement what is already in standard libraries

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code for your `stats()` method. Perhaps it will enlighten you.

```
private static void stats(String[] args)
{
    final int count = args.length - 1;
    int total = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i + 1]);
        total += a;
        if (max < a) max = a;
        if (min > a) min = a;
    }
    System.out.println("Total " + total);
    System.out.println("Max " + max);
    System.out.println("Min " + min);
    System.out.printf("Average " + "%.2f\n", (double)total / count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be a duplicate question, but not able to find previous answer easily.
No need to do it manually since java 8, unless you are being paid for KLOC

```
String[] strings = ...;
IntSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(strings)
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::parseInt));
```

See [What's New in Java 8](https://leanpub.com/whatsnewinjava8/read#leanpub-auto-collectors-and-statistics)

Comment: this bycicle is being invented again and again :) [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839041/java-highest-and-lowest-numbers), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201579/how-do-i-determine-the-highest-and-lowest-value-in-user-entered-input), ...

Comment: Unless, of course, you're learning how to program for the first time, in which case finding highest, lowest, and average numbers is a good introduction to how loops work.

Comment: I don't disagree with your premise (and thus didn't down-vote), but the fact is that questions like this one are *almost certainly* students trying to learn, and this won't be particularly instructive for them, because it doesn't address the source of their confusion.  Thanks for showing this, though.  I didn't know about it, either.