# How can the minimum and maximum of a list of integers in a .text file be determined?

Tags: java, eclipse

My objective is to read a .text file filled with an unknown amount of integers and find the sum/average/min/and max. 
I have it down to finding the sum and average, I just need help finding the min and max from a .text file. Here is what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner file = null; //initializes file to empty
    int cnt=0;
    int sum = 0;
    double average;
    try
    {
        //attempt to open file.
        file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("pd06.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not found. Error 404");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    while(file.hasNextInt())
    {

        sum+=file.nextInt();//sums all numbers within the file 
        cnt++;              // counts all numbers in file.      
                            // Used in average. 
    }
    average = (double)sum / cnt; //Average

    System.out.println("There are "+cnt+" numbers in "
            + "the file.");
    System.out.println("The sum of which is "+sum);
    System.out.printf("The average of all %d numbers "
            + "is %.2f\n",cnt ,average);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the garbled code ... I'm a first time user, for stack overflow.

Comment: duplicate of [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729459/lowest-and-highest-number-in-an-array), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839041/java-highest-and-lowest-numbers), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201579/how-do-i-determine-the-highest-and-lowest-value-in-user-entered-input)

Comment: `final IntSummaryStatistics statistics = IntStream.generate(file::nextInt).summaryStatistics();`

Comment: if you prefer to re-implement a library function - check first how professional programmers did it [IntSummaryStatistics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temporary variable(one for max and one for min). Store the integer you get from the file in a variable and compare it every time with the max and min variables. Update those two variables whenever you find the new max and min values.

```
int number = 0;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //Give lowest 'int' number (-2147483648) if your file has -ve numbers also.
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //Highest value for int
while(file.hasNext()) {
    number = file.nextInt();
    if(number > max) {
        max = number; //assuming you have all positive numbers in your file
    }
    if(number < min) {
        min = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattSobocinski, 2^32 is much larger than that. The max value for a signed 32-bit integer is 2^31 - 1  (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=2%5E31+-1)

Comment: You're welcome. Take care if you would like to do this with a `Double`, the static values for Double do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set `min` and `max` equal to `number` only the first time around and use a boolean to only do that once like this.

```
    int number = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0; 
    boolean firstTime = true;
    while(file.hasNext()) {
        number = file.nextInt();
        if(firstTime)
        {
            max = number;
            min = number;
            firstTime = false;
        }
        if(number > max) 
            max = number;

        if(number < min) 
            min = number;
    }
```